# giving "Microsoft sharepoint soapserver soap server exception" while getting the list items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the list items by using the webservice reference model.
I am trying to get the details of the list as this

```
  SPSeriveReference.Lists client = new SPSeriveReference.Lists();

                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "pswd","MyDomain");
                XmlDocument mydoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlElement viewFileds = mydoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
                viewFileds.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
        "<FieldRef Name=\"Name\" />" +
        "<FieldRef Name=\"Address\" />";
                XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems("Manager", null, null, viewFileds, null, null, null); //a4af13f3-69f6-45e3-930d-8c2ce61a10fd
                //XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems("Manager", null, null, viewFileds, null, null, null);
                foreach (XmlNode node in listItems)
                {
                    if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name=="z:row")
                            {
                                string title = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].Name;
                                string name = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Name"].Name;
                                string address = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Address"].Name;
                                Console.WriteLine(title + " " + name + " " + address);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But this is giving run time exception as "Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException"
What is the solution for this one?
I verified the questions in stack overflow which were asked previously regarding the same error. But none of the provided the solution for this problem.

Comment: try to debug first and tell us which part of the code is throwing the exception. by reading the exception message/stacktrace/data properties you might get some more info (post them here too!) does the code work when you remove the viewFields from the call?

Comment: @AndreasScharf exception coming at line  `XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems("Manager", null, null, viewFileds, null, null, null);`

Comment: Catch the SoapException (as `se` for example) and print out se.Detail.OuterXml. That will give you a better error message